# G+ Android UI animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, google-plus

Can someone explain the ui (controls/animation) used in the latest google plus android application at the stream grid...
I know not many are using g+ those days, but the latest android ui is really nice.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like a basic vertical(in portrait, anyway) coverflow implementation. Anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: Landscape mode (tablet version), where there are multiple sizes and some kind of animation which is different from the default one